# Discord.js bot doesn't actually kick member after mentioned

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a kick command for my Discord bot, however I'm not sure why it does not kick the member after mentioned.
When I use the command @kick itself without anything it works and says *"ERROR: You need to mention a member"*.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: "This command kicks members.",
    execute(message, args){
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (member) {
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id)
            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("User has been successfully kicked.")
        }
        else {
            message.channel.send('**ERROR:** You need to mention a member.')
        }
    }
}
```

Also, yes I have checked the bot permissions, it has administrator.

Comment: Is your command used like the `@botName kick @member` or like this `!kick @member`

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (message.mentions.users.size === 1) {
  const member = client.users.fetch(message.mentions.users.first());
  member.Kick()
} 
else {
  message.reply("Mention a user.")
  // or its more than 1 mentions idk....
}
```

Comment: You should add some explanation how this fixes OP's issue. Like what's the difference between him pulling the member from some kind of cache vs. you fetching it from the `client`